# Strange behaviour with RegQueryValueEx whitch return value of another register

Tags: c++, excel, windows, path, registry

I want to the path of Excel.exe from the registry. So i used the following:

**I am using Windows64bits**

```
 RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, szKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey)
```

with

```
szKey = "\Classes\CLSID\{ExcelCLSID}\LocalServer",
```

this register contains "C:\PROGRA~1\MIF5BA~1\Office15\EXCEL.EXE /automation"

Used this to get the Excel.exe Path

```
RegQueryValueEx(hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, (BYTE*)szPath, &cSize)
```

So when building my solution for Platform **x64**, i get as path

```
C:\\PROGRA~1\\MIF5BA~1\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE /automation
```

which is **fine**, but when building my solution for **Win32** platform i get the 
following path

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE" /automation
```

which is **strange** because this value is stored in the following registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{ExcelCLSID}\
```

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows registry maintains, more or less transparently, different information for 32-bit and 64-bit applications running in the same environment. The `Wow6432Node` you see indicates that the value for that key is specific to 32-bit applications running on a 64-bit version of Windows.

You can disable the default registry redirection (see [RegDisableReflectionKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724858(v=vs.85).aspx)), but in the majority of cases this isn't what you want to do.

See the information on registry redirection [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: i think the issue is in the mask that specifies the desired access rights to the key to be opened so for reading from windows64bits registries when running a 32bits process i should use **KEY_READ |KEY_WOW64_64KEY** instead of using **KEY_READ** only in the call of RegOpenKeyEx.